# FileNotFoundException when getting a list that EXISTS?

Tags: 2010, list, development

I am having the following exception when trying to get a list that I know it exists.

yes, I know the using should not be used in this case but thats not my code :), but I dont think thats the problem

```
 using (SPWeb CurrentSite = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb)
            {
                string listUrl = string.Format("{0}/Lists/RequestAccess", CurrentSite.Url);
                SPList list = CurrentSite.GetList(listUrl);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per msdn [`SPWeb.GetList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) accepts server relative url, but you pass absolute url, may be this is the issue.

Comment: Use the CurrentSite.ServerRelativeUrl.  Also ensure to check for the trailling backslash so you dont get two of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing issues with 
    SpWeb.Getlist() 
then instead of that you can
    SpWeb.Lists["ListName"]
which takes list title as parameter. no need to provide the URL.